# Proving a tricky Recurrence Relation for the k + 1 case

Tags: math, recurrence

I am absolutely stumped on this one.

```
T(n) = { 3, if n = 2 || T(n - 1) + (n/4), if n > 2

Prove by induction that T(n) = (n^2 + n + 18) / 8  [V n >= 2]
```

I know how to execute a proof by induction, but for some reason I cannot solve this expression for the k + 1 case.

Any help would be most excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we choose `n = 2`:

```
T(n = 2) = (2^2 + 2 + 18) / 8 = 24 / 8 = 3
```

Great, that works. Now we know that there is a number `k >= 2` that fulfills the definition of `T(n)`. Then, let's set `n = k+1` for an arbitrary `k >= 2`:

```
T(n = k+1) = ((k+1)^2 + k + 1 + 18) / 8
           = (k^2 + 2k + 1 + k + 1 + 18) / 8
           = (k^2 + k + 18) / 8 + (2 + 2k) / 8
           = T(k) + k/4
```

That is exactly what the definition of `T(n)` says.

∎